# Add specific property from belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel

I want my return object looks like this:

```
{
    id: "1",
    category_name: "Update Category56945",
    menutype_name: 'some name',
    menutype: {
        name: 'some name',
        ...
    }
}
```

Basically I want one property (menutype.name) to be shown at the top level. But was not able to do it with this:

```
$cats = Category::with(['menutype', 'menutype.name as menutype_name'])->get();
```

I got an error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::name()".

Here is my model setup ([code snippet](http://laravel.io/bin/W44Ba#17-20,26-27,29,33-34,36,38,40)):

```
   <?php
        class MenuType extends Eloquent {

            protected $fillable = array('name');

            function category() {
                return $this->hasMany('Category');
            }
        }

        class Category extends Eloquent {

            protected $fillable = array('name','maxitems', 'menutype_id');

            function menutype() {
                return $this->belongsTo('MenuType');
            }
        }

        /*
        * When run this, i want my object looks like this: 
        * 
    {
        id: "1",
        category_name: "Update Category56945",
        menutype_name: 'some name',
        menutype: {
            ....
        }
    }
    */

       $cats = Category::with(['menutype', 'menutype.name as menutype_name'])->get();

// get error
// Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::name()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your category model add an accessor for menu item name.

```
public function getMenutypeNameAttribute($value) {
  return $this->menutype->name;
}
```

Then you can load the categories and access the menutype name.

To append that to json add the following.

```
protected $appends = array('menutype_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that in your select statement. Assuming the `Category` and `MenuType` tables are `categories` and `menutypes`, respectively:

```
Category::select('categories.*', 'menutypes.name')
    ->join('menutypes', 'categories.id', '=', 'menutypes.id')
    ->with('menutype')
    ->get();
```